# CountVectorizer has no attribute error in python when used for BOW

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to build Bag of Words feature-set

This code was working fine before but now gives this error

> AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute
> 'get_feature_names'

I googled this error but what I got is that I sklearn library is old

I upgraded the sklearn library and now sure it is the latest 1.3.0

does anyone know why is this error and how to fix it?

here is my code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def BOW(df):
  CountVec = CountVectorizer() # to use only  bigrams ngram_range=(2,2)
  Count_data = CountVec.fit_transform(df)
  Count_data = Count_data.astype(np.uint8)
  cv_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Count_data.toarray(),columns=CountVec.get_feature_names())
  return cv_dataframe.astype(np.uint8)

dfMethod = BOW(df_reps["Txt"])
```

Comment: i found the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724805/attributeerror-countvectorizer-object-has-no-attribute-get-feature-names